# Can't start Flutter project with Android Emulator in Android Studio and Mac M1

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

I can't run or debug start a Flutter project in Android Emulator. Even if android emulator works normally, when I run the project the editor always gives me this error:

```
 Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1607)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1497)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1504)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1308)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1271)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:733)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:850)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:191)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

My MAC is 2020 MacBook Pro with M1 chip, my system is Ventura 3.0.1 and Flutter 3.3.8. This problem was there before upgrading MacOS to Ventura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select ARM Images section in System Image while creating a new Android Device.
As seen below: [image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild your .gradle file.

For macOS:

```
cd ~
rm -rf .gradle
```

[Github Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/73852)

Comment: Still gives me same error